# Is there a web based file manager for linux?

Tags: software-rec, web, file-manager

I need a filemanager for user space (i.e. /home) for my users that is accessible using a web browser. It doesn't have to be super featured, just the basic folder browsing, click to view / download a file / change folders, delete, upload.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Webmin](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Introduction) is providing a web based [file manager](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/File_Manager).

[image]

However, it is using the java plugin so has some trouble with recent browsers and JVMs. Hopefully, there is a new, html5 based, replacement being developed, [filemin](https://github.com/Real-Gecko/filemin), which might suit your needs.

[image]

See also this [discussion](https://www.virtualmin.com/node/36839).

Answer (score 4):

[FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP)? I think most browsers support it directly. If not a plugin.